# Loop over two lists and append items in django model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have two lists A and B:

truck_objects:

```
[<truck_name: Tempo 407 1500>, <truck_name: Tempo 407 1500>]
```

master_values:

```
[{<Truckdb: Truckdb object (136)>: [<ItemBatch: Iphone>, <ItemBatch: Iphone>, <ItemBatch: Iphone>]}, {<Truckdb: Truckdb object (254)>: [<ItemBatch: Iphone>, <ItemBat
ch: Iphone>, <ItemBatch: Iphone>]}]
```

I looped over both of them and tried to save the list in dictionaries to a model.

The list I want to save is this:

```
[<ItemBatch: Iphone>, <ItemBatch: Iphone>, <ItemBatch: Iphone>]
```

Code:

```
for i in range(len(truck_objects)):
    for j in range(len(master_values)):

        if i==j:
            DispatchPlan.objects.create(truck_name=truck_objects[i],items=master_values[something here])
```

How can I do that? what do i replace "something here" with so that I get the list?

Answer (score 2):

You wouldn't do it like this at all. Not only is it extremely inefficient to have that nested loop, in Python you should almost never iterate over `range(len(something))` but always directly over the something.

In this case, you should zip the lists together and iterate over the result:

```
for truck, master in zip(truck_objects, master_values):
    DispatchPlan.objects.create(truck_name=truck, items=master)
```

Comment: Wouldn't that zip items from truck_objects and the dictionaries from master values together? making `items ={<Truckdb: Truckdb object (136)>: [<ItemBatch: Iphone>, <ItemBatch: Iphone>, <ItemBatch: Iphone>]}` i.e a dictionary whereas I wanted the list inside the dictionary